# sudo command does not work when strace is attached with PID of bash

Tags: centos, sudo, strace

I am taking logs of command executed by user in a output file by attaching PID of BASH in `strace`.

`$ strace -q -f -e execve -p $$ -o <outputFile>`

It is working fine and I am getting all command list in output file.

But I face another problem. I cannot run `sudo` command when `strace` is attached with BASH PID.

I am getting the below error:

`sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?`

I checked `setuid` is set on `sudo` binary

`---s--x--x. 1 root root 123832 Mar 22 11:35 /usr/bin/sudo`

`sudo` is working fine when I stop `strace`.

Is this a bug or there is any technical reason? Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other ways to log all the commands executed by a user. With `sysdig` installed one might run something like

```
# sysdig "user.name = jdoe and evt.type = execve"
```

to log all `execve(2)` calls by `jdoe`; the `-p` option to `sysdig` can customized the output format, etc.

Another way would be to use `SystemTap` which has the advantage of being supported by RedHat; here we assume `jdoe` has a UID of `1000`;

```
probe begin {
    printf("begin trace...\n\n")
}

probe syscall.execve.return {
    if (uid() != 1000) next;
    printf("runs %s[%d]: %s\n", execname(), pid(), cmdline_str());
}
```

this can then be run via something like

```
# stap-prep
...
# stap whatyousavedtheaboveas.stp
```

Both methods will likely require adjustments to capture exactly what you need, handle error conditions where an `execve` fails, etc. On the plus side, `sysdig` and `SystemTap` are vastly more efficient than `strace` (run `vmstat 1` and watch how `strace` pushes context switches through the roof when running).

Answer (score 2):

The [manual for `strace`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) mentions that:

> **BUGS**
>          Programs that use the setuid bit do not have effective user ID privileges while being traced.

Though I do suspect it has more to do with the security implications of debugging a setuid process, than a bug. If I'm not mistaken, `strace` uses the same tracing interface as, say, `gdb`, and it allows among other things to modify the memory of the running process. Being able to do that to a process that runs with more privilege than you're supposed to have, would be
 a bad idea.

Comment: Thank you for your response!
Is there any other way to log all the command executed by any user instead of getting from .bash_history?

Comment: @SouravMaity, depends on what you need to use the log for. Is it security-related loogging (accounting), where you need to consider a hostile user trying to evade it, or are you just doing it "for yourself". What other requirements are there. You may want to post another question about that.